# Get information from Web Service Oracle SOA Suite in Java

Tags: java, web-services, soap, soa, suite

We've made a web service according to the book: "Getting Started With Oracle SOA Suite 11g R1 – A Hands-On Tutorial"

We followed the guide like in chapter 5, but now we are having problems finding how we call the web services from a Java project.

Does someone have a tutorial or a good link to documentation how we can call the web service from a java project? Because we are stuck, and can't find a way to call the web service.

Regards,
Tristan

Comment: WebServices usually have a "wsdl" file which can be accessed over a URL provided from the WebService.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a web service from a java project you need to obtain a web-service client for that service (or generate one from WSDL).

First of all I would suggest that you make sure that the WebService is deployed and functional. To check this you can use [SoapUi](http://www.soapui.org/) project.

Secondly try to either generate the web-service client (this step varies depending on how you developed the web-service)

Finally you import the web-service client into your java project and follow one of the many tutorials on how to connect web-service clients to the web-service. ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXRPC5.html))